# Does C have any tools for doing string addition?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I'm making a function that returns the derivative of a function that is represented as a tree like

```
      /   +    \
     *          ^
   /   \      /   \
  x     5   3.14   x
```

with nodes of the form

```
typedef struct node
{
    char * fx; // function
    struct node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    struct node * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

If a node has no children, e.g. `x`, `5`, `3.14` in the above example, then its `op`, `gx` and `hx` are `NULL`, and otherwise its `fx` is `NULL`.

My function for calculating the derivative looks like

```
char * deriveFromTree ( node * rt )
{
    char * buff = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    int curBuffIdx = 0;
    if (rt->op) // if rt is of the form rt = gx op hx
    {
        char * dgdx = deriveFromTree(rt->gx); // g'(x)
        char * dhdx = deriveFromTree(rt->hx); // h'(x)
        char thisop = *rt->op;
        if (thisop == '+' || thisop == '-')
        {
            // ... want to do equivalent of
            //     buff = dgdx + thisop + dhdx
        }
        else if (thisop == '*')
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (thisop == '/')
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (thisop == '^')
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    else // rt is a base expression -- x or a constant
    {
        buff[curBuffIdx] = strcmp(rt->fx, 'x') ? '1': '0';
    }
    buff[++curBuffIdx] = '\0';
    return buff;
}
```

but I'm getting tripped up on all the string addition. I could create from scratch a string adder, if there's already a compact way of doing

```
            // ... want to do equivalent of
            //     buff = dgdx + thisop + dhdx
```

then I'd like to use that tool.

Comment: The only "tool" used by C as such is the compiler. Otherwise, you might have a look at the standard's string library you are already using apparently. Also: what is a "string addition"?

Comment: `strcat` ....or I am missunderstandign your problem

Comment: Normally, "string addition" is interpreted as concatenation. Would it be more accurate to say what you want to do is "floating-point addition, where the numbers are stored as their decimal representation in a string"?

Comment: My personal preference depends on what capabilities are available. If I have dynamically allocated memory capabilities (`malloc`), I'll use a dynamic string library, similar to C++'s own `std::string` type, that will allow me to grow a string as necessary. Otherwise, I'll use something functionally similar to the nonstandard C function `strlcat` that will flag truncation as an error since it's never a good idea to allow loss of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your C standard library is GNU or *BSD, then you probably have `asprintf` available. You may need to enable a feature test macro to use it, though. If you don't have `asprintf` available, it can easily be defined in terms of the C standard `vsnprintf` function.

`asprintf` returns the result of the format as a newly-allocated string (which it is your responsibility to `free`). So you could write, for example:

```
char* buff;
int n = asprintf(&buff, "%s%c%s", dgdx, thisop, dhdx);
```

I usually use a wrapper function, which returns the string rather than the length, so you can write:

```
char* buff = concatf("%s%c%s", dgdx, thisop, dhdx);
```

Here are three simple implementations; the first will work on systems with `vasprintf`; the second on systems with Posix `vsnprintf`; and the third for Windows, which apparently implements a different `snprintf` interface.

```
// Version 1, systems which have vasprintf:
char* concatf(const char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list args;
  char* buf = NULL;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int n = vasprintf(&buf, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (n < 0) { free(buf); buf = NULL; }
  return buf;
}

// Version 2: Systems without vasprintf but with vsnprintf
char* concatf(const char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  char* buf = NULL;
  int n = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (n >= 0) {
    va_start(args, fmt);
    buf = malloc(n+1);
    if (buf) vsnprintf(buf, n+1, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
  }
  return buf;
}

// Version 3: Windows
// Apparently, the implementation of vsnprintf on Windows returns -1
// if not enough space has been provided. So here is the above code
// rewritten according to the documentation I found in
//  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w05tbk72%28VS.71%29.aspx
// and
//  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
// but totally untested. (If you try it, let me know)
char* concatf(const char* fmt, ...) {
  char* buf = NULL;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int n = _vscprintf(fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (n >= 0) {
    va_start(args, fmt);
    buf = malloc(n+1);
    if (buf) _vsnprintf(buf, n+1, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

That's the most concise equivalent I know of to string concatenation operators in other languages. (It's not necessarily the most efficient in execution time, but it probably is in programmer time.)

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is string concatenation, and the standard C library function for that is `strcat`, or better (because arguably safer) `strncat`.

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat

Comment: `strncat` is not safer. It has it's own can of worms, like not adding null terminator if the buffer is not large enough

Comment: truncating *isn't safe*. e.g.: imagine you're using those derivates for the steering of a vehicle...

Comment: @bolov: I would very well call a function that _does_ prevent buffer overflow - regardless of other issues - call safer than one which does _not_. The trailing `NUL` can be added after the function very easily, a buffer overflow cannot.

Comment: @bolov I do agree it's not inherently safer, but a coder thinking about maximum string lengths is forced to realize she/he can't copy more into a buffer than she/he allocated

Comment: @Olaf: silently ignoring truncation is anything but safe. with buffer overflow at least you have a good chance the app will crash, and somebody will notice the problem

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: So you state UB is better than well defined behaviour (it _Is_ know to truncate)? Good one! The NUL can be written easily always to the last entry. For the segfault: be happy to get one. Worst thing UB can produce is to get along unnoticed.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the application crashing with a segfault is just wishful thinking. The point is that you, as a programmer, should force yourself to consider your buffer sizes when you're doing string processing in C.

Comment: @Olaf: I didn't say it's *better*. It's still awful.

Comment: @Olaf on your side on this one, but really, truncating isn't inherently better than crashing -- but I agree, if you, as a programmer, know that there's a string of max so and so many chars and act like it, your program at least can behave predictably.

Comment: as long as you know the implications and of any of the `strcat` `strncat` and `strlcat` and take measures to protect yourself all are good. If you ignore them, all are bad. I.e. you can wrap `strcat` in an `if` and you are good, or you could not append the null terminating after a `strncat` and then pass that buffer to something like `printf` and you are f**ked.

Comment: So I have a patient's record for a hospital. I silently truncate the string, and it's just wiped out the warning about the patient's deadly drug allergy. But it's predictable. And "safer". Hurray.

Comment: I think @bolov nicely wrapped up this comment thread, people. let's move on. Dear original asker (OP), please realize that writing something that mangles strings in C is *hard* and you should try to rely on well-tested libraries to do your job.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: I did not state different. But I still think a lynx in my room is still better than a tiger. Of course you have to ensure the strings fit, but using strncat is still better, as a second line of defense than strcat.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You've got 52000+ rep. You should know better than to get worked up by a dispute. Olaf, I think Karoly agrees with you on safety aspects, the two of you just disagree on how to properly say what's more horrific. Don't be personal.

Comment: Oh, great! _My_ comments have been deleted without reason. So much for objectivity. When do you get this privilege? 50,000 reps+?

Comment: @Karoly: "Safer" does not mean "safe". I don't think anyone here means to claim that silently truncating the string is *safe*: just that it's *less unsafe* than allowing the buffer overflow (whether true or not; I think the very first comment makes a good point that it's *differently* unsafe, not *less* unsafe).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve cannot be done in plain C, because it has no operator overloading. You may use `strncat` for this, but be advised that this is quite low-level solution that requires you to manage memory manually.

You can do this cleanly in C++ using `std::string` or `std::wstring` objects, which have proper `operator+()`.

Alternatively you could implement your own string structure with appropriate, object-oriented API.