# Bison/Flext Concat Char *

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, bison, interpreter

I made a .l and a .y files for the parsing and the calculation result for my new language: it is working fine! A string like this:

> SET(IFEL(MAJEQ(IFEL(EQ(VAL(16),MUL(VAL(2),VAL(8))),VAL(11),VAL(10)),VAL(10)),MUL(VAL(3),VAL(4)),SUB(VAL(6),VAL(2))))

is correctly parsed and calculated by my two files:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
%}

//Symbols
%union
{
    char *str_val;
    int int_val;
};

%token OPEN;
%token CLOSE;
%token SET;
%token STORE;
%token MUL;
%token ADD;
%token DIV;
%token SUB;
%token ABS;
%token IFEL;
%token AND;
%token OR;
%token NOT;
%token MAJEQ;
%token MINEQ;
%token MAJ;
%token MIN;
%token EQ;
%token GET;
%token S; /* separator */
%token VAR;
%token VAL;
%token <int_val>    NUMBER
%token <str_val>    IDENTIFIER

%type <int_val> Exp
%type <int_val> Cond
%type <int_val> Check
%type <int_val> Var

%start Expression

%%

Expression:
    /* empty */
    | SET OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        printf("value set %d\n",$3);
    }
    | STORE OPEN VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE S Exp CLOSE
    {
        printf("var %s set on %d\n",$5,$8);
    }
    ;

Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        if($3==1){
            $$ = $5;
        }else{
            $$ = $7;
        }
    }
    | ADD OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3+$5;
    }
    | SUB OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3-$5;
    }
    | MUL OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3*$5;
    }
    | DIV OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3/$5; //TBD check div 0
    }
    | ABS OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3; //TBD
    }
    ;

Cond:
    NOT OPEN Cond CLOSE
    {
        int result = $3;
        if(result==1) $$ = 0;
        else $$ = 1;
    }
    | AND OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        int result1 = $3;
        int result2 = $5;
        if(result1==1 && result2==1) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;
    }
    | OR OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        int result1 = $3;
        int result2 = $5;
        if(result1==1 || result2==1) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;
    }
    | Check
    ;

Check:
    MAJ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        int val1 = $3;
        int val2 = $5;
        if(val1>val2) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;    
    }
    | MIN OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        int val1 = $3;
        int val2 = $5;
        if(val1<val2) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;    
    }
    | EQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        int val1 = $3;
        int val2 = $5;
        if(val1==val2) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;    
    }
    | MAJEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        int val1 = $3;
        int val2 = $5;
        if(val1>=val2) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;    
    }
    | MINEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        int val1 = $3;
        int val2 = $5;
        if(val1<=val2) $$ = 1;
        else $$ = 0;    
    }
    ;

Var:
    VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = atoi($3); //TBD 
    }
    | VAL OPEN NUMBER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3;
    }
    | GET OPEN CLOSE
    {
        $$ = 11; //TBD 
    }
    ;
%%
```

and

```
%{
#include <string>
#include "expression.tab.h"
void yyerror(char*);
extern void printVars();
int yyparse(void);
%}

%%

[ \t\n]+    { /* ignore */ };

"("         return(OPEN);
")"         return(CLOSE);
"SET"       return(SET);
"STORE"     return(STORE);
"MUL"       return(MUL);
"ADD"       return(ADD);
"DIV"       return(DIV);
"SUB"       return(SUB);
"ABS"       return(ABS);
"IFEL"      return(IFEL);
"NOT"       return(NOT);
"AND"       return(AND);
"OR"        return(OR);
"MAJEQ"     return(MAJEQ);
"MINEQ"     return(MINEQ);
"MAJ"       return(MAJ);
"MIN"       return(MIN);
"EQ"        return(EQ);
"VAR"       return(VAR);
"VAL"       return(VAL);
"GET"       return(GET);
","         return(S);

[[:digit:]]+  { yylval.int_val = atoi(yytext);   return NUMBER;}
[[:alnum:]]+  { yylval.str_val = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER;}

.           return yytext[0];

%%

void yyerror(char *s){ 
    printf("<ERR> %s at %s in this line:\n", s, yytext);
    }

int yywrap (void){
    }

int main(int num_args, char** args){
    if(num_args != 2) {printf("usage: ./parser filename\n"); exit(0);}
    FILE* file = fopen(args[1],"r");
    if(file == NULL) {printf("couldn't open %s\n",args[1]); exit(0);}
    yyin = file;
    yyparse();
    fclose(file);
}
```

But actually the value inside Var in input as you can see will not be static but should be dynamic. So my next step is to modify the project: instead of calculating should write a C++ code in order to make the calculation dynamic.

My questions:
1) do you have a better solution instead of concatenate every step a char * for making the code?
2) If not, can you help me to find a smart way to concatenate all the strings and solving the following error that I face while compiling:

> expression.y:75:43: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [2]’
>   and ‘char*’ to binary ‘operator+’    $$ = "("+$3+"-"+$5+")";

... I would like to don't use the "malloc" every time...

```
char* str;
str = malloc(1+strlen(text1)+strlen(text2));
strcpy(str, text1);
strcat(str, text2);
```

is there any smarter way? Following the flex and bison modified files:

expression.l

```
%{
#include <string>
#include "expression.tab.h"
void yyerror(char*);
extern void printVars();
int yyparse(void);
%}

%%

[ \t\n]+    { /* ignore */ };

"("         return(OPEN);
")"         return(CLOSE);
"SET"       return(SET);
"STORE"     return(STORE);
"MUL"       return(MUL);
"ADD"       return(ADD);
"DIV"       return(DIV);
"SUB"       return(SUB);
"ABS"       return(ABS);
"IFEL"      return(IFEL);
"NOT"       return(NOT);
"AND"       return(AND);
"OR"        return(OR);
"MAJEQ"     return(MAJEQ);
"MINEQ"     return(MINEQ);
"MAJ"       return(MAJ);
"MIN"       return(MIN);
"EQ"        return(EQ);
"VAR"       return(VAR);
"VAL"       return(VAL);
"GET"       return(GET);
","         return(S);

([a-z0-9]+)|([0-9]+.[0-9]+)     { yylval.str_val = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER;}

.           return yytext[0];

%%

void yyerror(char *s){ 
    printf("<ERR> %s at %s in this line:\n", s, yytext);
    }

int yywrap (void){
    }

int main(int num_args, char** args){
    if(num_args != 2) {printf("usage: ./parser filename\n"); exit(0);}
    FILE* file = fopen(args[1],"r");
    if(file == NULL) {printf("couldn't open %s\n",args[1]); exit(0);}
    yyin = file;
    yyparse();
    fclose(file);
}
```

expression.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
%}

//Symbols
%union
{
    char *str_val;
    int int_val;
};

%token OPEN;
%token CLOSE;
%token SET;
%token STORE;
%token MUL;
%token ADD;
%token DIV;
%token SUB;
%token ABS;
%token IFEL;
%token AND;
%token OR;
%token NOT;
%token MAJEQ;
%token MINEQ;
%token MAJ;
%token MIN;
%token EQ;
%token GET;
%token S; /* separator */
%token VAR;
%token VAL;

%token <str_val> IDENTIFIER

%type <str_val> Exp
%type <str_val> Cond
%type <str_val> Check
%type <str_val> Var

%start Expression

%%

Expression:
    /* empty */
    | SET OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        printf("%s\n",$3);
    }
    | STORE OPEN VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE S Exp CLOSE
    {
        printf("var %s with following code:\n%s\n",$5,$8);
    }
    ;

Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+" == 'true') ? ("+$5+") : ("+$7+")";
    }
    | ADD OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"+"+$5+")"; 
    }
    | SUB OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"-"+$5+")"; 
    }
    | MUL OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"*"+$5+")"; 
    }
    | DIV OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"/"+$5+")"; //TBD check div 0
    }
    | ABS OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+">0) ? "+$3+" : "(+$3+"*(-1))";
    }
    ;

Cond:
    NOT OPEN Cond CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"=='true') ? 'false' : 'true'";
    }
    | AND OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"=='true' && "+$5+"=='true') ? 'true' : 'false'";
    }
    | OR OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"=='true' || "+$5+"=='true') ? 'true' : 'false'";
    }
    | Check
    ;

Check:
    MAJ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+">"+$5+") ? 'true' : 'false'";
    }
    | MIN OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"<"+$5+") ? 'true' : 'false'";  
    }
    | EQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"=="+$5+") ? 'true' : 'false'"; 
    }
    | MAJEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+">="+$5+") ? 'true' : 'false'";
    }
    | MINEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "("+$3+"<="+$5+") ? 'true' : 'false'";
    }
    ;

Var:
    VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        //TBD check if variable exists in the engine
        $$ = $3;
    }
    | VAL OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        //TBD check correct value
        $$ = $3;
    }
    | GET OPEN CLOSE
    {
        $$ = "getField()"; //TBD to implement in the engine
    }
    ;
%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I solved the issue in this way:

```
...
Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string t3 = $7;
        string result = "("+t1+" == 'true') ? ("+t2+") : ("+t3+")";
        $$ = (char*)result.c_str();
    }
...
```

It is working fine...

Comment: You cannot use the value returned by result.c_str() after result has been destructed at the end of the block. So if it works on some input, it is purely by accident.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to do string concatenation without some form of memory allocation. Of course, it is possible avoid avoid `malloc` -- you could use `new` instead, or hide the memory allocation inside of a `std::string` or `std::stringstream` -- but in the end, you're going to have to deal with dynamic memory allocation, and furthermore with releasing the memory when you no longer need it.

It's worth noting that your (correct) use of `strdup` in your scanner action for `IDENTIFIER` is a memory leak, because you never free the allocated memory. So you already need to deal with this issue.

As you note, doing string concatenation in C can be pretty clunky. In a case like this, it's worth the trouble to reduce the clunkiness. My preferred solution is my wrapper function `concatf`, whose prototype is just like printf except that it returns a malloc'd character string instead of printing. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687023/1566221) for implementations on various platforms).

With the help of this function, it would be possible to write:

```
Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = concatf("(%s == 'true') ? (%s) : (%s)", $3, $5, $7);
    }
```

Note that  `x == 'true'` is not valid C++. You probably meant `== true`, but that's a dangerous idiom; better is an explicit cast to `bool` (although that's actually redundant in the context of the ternary operator), so I think you actually want

```
        $$ = concatf("bool(%s) ? (%s) : (%s)", $3, $5, $7);
```

or just

```
        $$ = concatf("(%s) ? (%s) : (%s)", $3, $5, $7);
```

But, as mentioned above, that results in memory leaks because the malloc'd strings are never freed. So let's fix that. First, in each action, it is necessary to explicitly free all malloc'd values which are never used again. In simple cases like yours, that will be all malloc'd values, except for unit productions in which the malloc'd value is just assigned to a different non-terminal. Since all `IDENTIFIER` have semantic values created by `strdup`, it's reasonable to assume that all `str_val` values have been malloc'd (and this needs to be a constraint; if you ever create a `str_val` value from a literal character string, you'll end up with a problem). Now, we can write the rule:

```
Exp:
    Var  { /* No free needed; this is a unit production */ }
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        $$ = concatf("(%s) ? (%s) : (%s)", $3, $5, $7);
        free($3); free($5); free($7);
    }
```

Another example. Note the added `strdup` in the last rule.

```
Var:
    VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3; /* No free needed; value is moved on the stack */
    }
    | VAL OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3; /* As above */
    }
    | GET OPEN CLOSE
    {
        $$ = strdup("getField()"); /* str_val's must be malloc'd */
    }
    ;
```

(There are alternatives to calling `strdup` on literals, but usually the use case is uncommon, and the overhead is slight.)

That style will handle all cases where rule actions are executed, but there are also occasions when bison will discard values from the stack without every invoking a rule. That will happen during error recovery, and at the end of an unsuccessful parse when the parser stack is non-empty. To assist with this case, bison lets you declare a [destructor action](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Destructor-Decl.html), which will be invoked on each stack value which it discards. In this case, the declaration is almost trivial:

```
%destructor { free($$); } <str_val>
```

Comment: Found very usefull the suggestions for free all malloc'd! Thank you very much. Also the concatf() is going to help me to have a better code, I'm going to try it after caring of memory. :) Again many thanks