# How to use asprintf in a flex rule, when _GNU_SOURCE not set?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

In order to ensure that the `asprintf` function is visible in the header file `<stdio.h>`, I have followed the advice of the man page and put:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
// ... uses of asprintf();
```

This works in normal C programs, although presumably only on GNU/Linux and not on the BSDs.

I would like to be able to use the same trick in a flex lexer, e.g.:

```
%{
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

\"[^\"].+\" {
  asprintf(&(yylval.string), "%s", yytext);
  return STRING;
}

%%

// ...
```

but I get a compile warning (`implicit-function-declaration`) for `asprintf`.

Upon further investigation, this is because in the C file that flex generates it includes `<stdio.h>` before my preamble code, without defining _GNU_SOURCE first.

How can I write code which uses this function which

- compiles correctly inside flex rules, and
- (*optionally*) also works in non-GNU environments?

Comment: another apporach would be to adjust your build system to pass `-D_GNU_SOURCE`

Comment: However, if flex is using that header without that declaration, there is a possibility that this will change its behaviour. But that would have worked as well, yes.

Comment: That's really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having re-checked [the book](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/21st_Century_C.html?id=pN6-oAEACAAJ&hl=en) that got me into the habit of using `asprintf`, I have discovered that it is indeed a GNU extension.

It is available in a GCC library called `libiberty`, which you can use in place of the `_GNU_SOURCE` macro.

I was able to install this on Ubuntu 15.10 and Debian 8.2 using:

```
sudo apt-get install libiberty-dev
```

I then modified the preamble to include:

```
%{
#include <libiberty/libiberty.h>
%}
```

and everything worked without any warnings.

Assuming that a libiberty package is available for non-Linux distributions (and given that it is part of GCC I would assume this would be the case) this solution should work cross platform (on POSIX-ish OS's.)

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30687023/1566221 . If you abstract the call to asprintf to a support library, you only need to include that library's header, and you can also hide the infrastructure to decide which version to use.