# Bison: alternate order of $1, $2 etc gives wrong output

Tags: c, bison

I'm using bison to build a parser for educational purposes. Here is my very simple grammar:

```
program: KW_VAR ident {printf("var %s\n", $2);} ;

ident:
 | IDENTIFIER OP_PLUS IDENTIFIER {sprintf($$, "%s + %s\n", $1, $3);}
 ;
```

where KW_VAR represents the word 'var' and OP_PLUS the operator '+'.

**var hello + hi** is an acceptable phrase for this grammar. So when I use the code above, everything is ok and printf gives: **var hello + hi** as expected. But when I try to change the order of $1, $3 in sprintf, as below, printf gives: **var hi + hi +**. What I expect was **var hi + hello**.

```
program: KW_VAR ident {printf("var %s\n", $2);} ;

ident:
 | IDENTIFIER OP_PLUS IDENTIFIER {sprintf($$, "%s + %s\n", $3, $1);}
 ;
```

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider the following code:

```
const char* greeting = "Hello";
const char* greeted = "world";
char* message;
sprintf(message, "%s, %s!", greeting, greeted);
```

Is that valid? **No!** `message` was never initialized, so it points into outer space. You certainly can't pass it to `sprintf` and expect everything to work out.

So what might we expect with the following?

```
sprintf($$, "%s + %s\n", $3, $1);
```

We haven't initialized `$$`, so again we're overprinting some random memory. Except in this case, it isn't quite random, because just before the bison-generated parser executes any action, it first does this:

```
$$ = $1;
```

So effectively, the `sprintf` call is:

```
sprintf($1, "%s + %s\n", $3, $1);
```

and that is undefined behaviour of a different form. Quoting from `man 3 sprintf` on an Ubuntu system,

> the standards explicitly note that the results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when calling `sprintf()`

The manpage notes that although it is not permitted by the standard, with certain gcc and glibc versions, if a source buffer overwrites itself (as a way of appending to a buffer), it might appear to work.

Of course, that assumes that there is actually enough space in the string pointed to be `$1` to hold the result of `sprintf`. Is there? Who knows? We don't see where `$1` came from.

The semantic value `$1` was filled in by the lexical scanner. The correct way of doing that in the scanner would be something like the following (although the real pattern might include underscores):

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*   {  yylval = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
```

In that case, the semantic value `$1` will not be long enough, since it will be exactly as long as necessary to copy the identifier, and no longer. Even if the `sprintf` "seems to work", it will be a buffer overrun, and random memory will be overwritten. [Note 1]

---

So, what to do? The simple solution, if you have it, is to use `asprintf`, which is similar to `sprintf` except that it allocates a new buffer. With that function, you could write the bison action:

```
asprintf(&$$, "%s + %s\n", $3, $1);
```

(Note the `&`: `asprintf` requires a pointer to a `char*`, and returns the allocated memory address into the pointed-to argument. So at the end of this call, `$$` will be pointing at a newly-allocated buffer with the correct string.)

If your system doesn't have `asprintf`, or you'd like to be prepared for systems which don't, check out the implementations of `concatf` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687023/1566221)

---

#### Notes

1. A lot of the time, you will see the following in lexical scanners written by students:

   ```
   [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*   {  yylval = yytext;  /* DON'T DO THIS!!! */
                                return IDENTIFIER;
                             }
   ```

   That's incorrect because `yytext` points at a temporary buffer which belongs to the lexical scanner itself. There is no guarantee that by the time the parser gets around to looking at the pointer, it will still be pointing at the same data. Or, indeed, at anything; it is quite possible that the scanner will have freed that buffer and started using a different one. So that's already a problem. And if that's not enough of a problem, the `sprintf` will then overwrite *the scanner's input buffer*, which might have interesting consequences when the next token is read.

Comment: Thanks @rici for your analytic and useful answer. Fortunately I'm at the beginning of the project so your answer will be helpful for me.

Comment: I have two more questions: 1) Do you think it is safe to use asprintf or there is another way to do what I want. 2) If yes, then do I have to use free function somewhere for $$?

Comment: @giannis.t: I use asprintf a lot; it is safer and less fiddly than the alternatives. For me, Windows and legacy systems are not a concern but the link in the answer shows how to deal with them; it is not difficult...

Comment: ... Of course, you need to free allocated memory. That includes the `strdup` (or equivalent) in your lexer. (And if you are not making a copy of `yytext`, read the note at the bottom carefully.) Memory management is a problem. There are a number of useful questions about it on SO and also a section in the bison manual.

Comment: Ok @rici I will follow your advice and I hope to make it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `strdup(..)` suggestion saved my day