# lex and yacc program to convert infix to prefix

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am new to lex and yacc programs.I have been trying to write a yacc program which takes as input an arithmetic expression and gives prefix notation as output.
here is my lex code.

```
%{
#include<string.h>
#include"pre.tab.h"
%}
%%
"*"|"/"|"+"|"-"|"("|")" {return yytext[0];}
[0-9]+ {yylval.name=(char*)malloc(yyleng+1);
   strcpy(yylval.name,yytext);
   return NUM;}
\n {return(0);}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]* {yylval.name=(char*)malloc(yyleng+1);
      strcpy(yylval.name,yytext);
      return ID;}
. {}
%%
int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
```

Here is my YACC code

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char buf[10];
%}

%union
{
  char *name;
}
%token<name>NUM ID
%type<name>E 
%left'+''-'
%left'*''/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%%
S:E  {printf("\n%s",$1);}
;
E:E'*'E {buf[0]='\0';strcpy($$,strcat(strcpy(buf,"*"),strcat($1,$3)));}
|E'/'E {buf[0]='\0';strcpy($$,strcat(strcpy(buf,"/"),strcat($1,$3)));}
|E'+'E {buf[0]='\0';strcpy($$,strcat(strcpy(buf,"+"),strcat($1,$3)));}
|E'-'E {buf[0]='\0';strcpy($$,strcat(strcpy(buf,"-"),strcat($1,$3)));}
|ID
|NUM
|'('E')'{strcpy($$,$2);}
;
%%
main()
{
yyparse();
}
int yyerror(char *s) {fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);}
```

I am not getting any output when I input an arithmetic expression in parantheses. Eg : Input : 1+(2*3) output : +*23*23. I have tried to rectify the code many times but in vain.

Comment: Space bar broken? Do you get anything? Syntax error?

Comment: @EJP I  don't get any output. When I input 1 + 2 nothing is displayed in the command prompt. Same is the case when I input 1+2

Comment: Check out the semi-standard functions `strdup` and `asprintf`, avaiable on Linux, Windows, OSX, *BSD, and most unix-like systems...

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings do not magically expand like they do in other languages. (Or, better said, there really is no string object.) You cannot call `strcat(a, b)` unless you have already ensured that the char array `a` has enough space following the NUL terminator to append `b`.

You can't `strcat` to a string literal, because not only is there not enough space, but also the string literal may be in read-only memory.

And you can't strcpy to an unassigned variable and expect sufficient memory to be allocated automatically. (Although `$$` is not actually an uninitialised variable, since it is initialised to the value of `$1`.)

So your code is full of buffer overruns, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I corrected my code which has been updated above but now a new error came up. Input : 1+(2*3) output : +*23*23

Comment: @user46663: When you write `strcpy($$, ...)`, what buffer is `$$` pointing at? Did you allocate it? Do you have any idea how much space is available in it? You really need to understand how to do string manipulation in C in order to do what you want to do. (And please don't edit your question after it has been answered; it makes the answers incorrect or even irrelevant.)

Comment: I know which buffer $$ is pointing at. Perhaps you need to brush up your Yacc skills before commenting. If  you dont know the answer you shouldn't answer it vaguely.

Comment: @user46663: So in the production `'(' E ')' {strcpy($$,$2);}`, for example, `$$` will have been initialized by `$$ = $1` prior to the rule running, but `$1` refers to the terminal `(`. Does that even have a semantic value associated with it? Has it been initialized to anything? ... SO is not a "please write my code for me" service, and my answer is intended to point you in a useful direction. You are, of course, completely free to ignore it.

Comment: @user46663: Oh, and by the way, in the case where you are reducing `E op E` for some op, and `$1` is the result of the reduction of `E:ID` or `E:NUM`, the buffer for `strcat($1, $3)` will have been created by the lexer using `malloc(yyleng+1)`, so it clearly does not have any space available for an append. I hope that is specific enough for you.

Comment: I can't think of anything. I have been working on this code for 4 days and I have tried most of the things. It would be great if you corrected the code.

Comment: how do i use the -v option in bison? I tried using bison -v pre.y but no table appeared

Comment: @user46663 It should show up as a file called `pre.output`

Comment: Thanks @rici .. I tried rectifying the code but failed. Why don't you please edit the code? Or tell me another way to approach the question

Comment: @user46663: As I said, your problem is not with bison, but with understanding how to manipulate strings in C. Personally, I tend to use `asprintf`, although it doesn't exist on Windows so you need to use `snprintf` to implement it. For simple string concatenation, you could use the same technique you use to duplicate the string in your scanner: work out how long the result will be (by adding lengths); add 1 for the NUL byte, allocate a buffer of that size, and then copy the pieces into the allocated buffer. Don't forget to `free` the buffer when you're done with it.

Comment: @user46663: Here's an example of using `asprintf`, along with the function I usually use and implementations for various OSs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30687023/1566221

Answer (score -1):

I used `strdup` function to copy the contents into `$$` instead of `strcpy`. It worked well for me.