# LEX -YACC parser for infix-to-prefix translation

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

Translation schemes:

```
expr -> {print("+")} expr + term
      | {print("-")} expr - term
      | term
term -> {print("*")} term * factor
      | {print("/")} term / factor
      | factor
factor -> digit {print(digit)}
        | (expr)
```

Above  grammar will print the expression in prefix form. For this grammar it is not possible to write the parser.
how could we write the lex and yacc program to convert infix to prefix. 
I follow this [lex and yacc program to convert infix to prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383448/lex-and-yacc-program-to-convert-infix-to-prefix) but not getting proper output. Any idea how to write the parser.

Comment: The [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Infix-Calc) includes a gentle introduction to the yacc/bison tool, with examples of simple calculator grammars.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you use real working code as a model, rather than starting with a SO question about code which certainly does not work. (If it worked, thw question would not have been asked.)

Comment: 'Not getting proper output' is not the same thing as 'not possible to write the parser', which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't output operator tokens until after you reduce rules with them (recognize them), you'll need to save the string for the expression before the operator (rather than outputting it as you see it) so it can be emitted *after* the operator.  This means that your rules need to build strings with the translation and only output the string only after parsing a complete expression.

There are a number of ways of building strings in C.  You can use `asprintf` or `malloc` + `strcpy`/`strcat`/`sprintf`, and then worry about when to properly free stuff afterwards.  Or you can use some sort of string pool that tracks the memory for you and can deal with cleanup.