# Infix to Prefix Conversion using Recursion

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, parse-tree

I am struggling to find the infix to prefix translation scheme.

**I have figured the infix to postfix translation sceme :**

```
expr -> Term, Rest
Rest -> +Term, { print('+') } , Rest | -Term, { print('-') }, Rest | epsilon
Term -> Factor, Rest_
Rest_ -> *Factor, { print('*') }, Rest_ | /Factor, { print('/') }, Rest_ | epsilon
Factor -> Digit | (expr)
Digit -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

**And my infix to postfix conversion code according to the above translation scheme :**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const char input[] = "9-5*2";
int index = 0;
char LookAhead = input[index];

void Match(char newChar);
void Factor();
void Rest_();
void Rest();
void Term();
void Expression();


int main(){
    Expression();
    return 0;
}

void Match(char newChar){
    if(newChar == LookAhead){
        index++;
        LookAhead = input[index];
    }
}

void Expression(){
    Term();
    Rest();
}

void Term(){
    Factor();
    Rest_();
}

void Rest(){
    if(LookAhead == '+'){
        Match('+');
        Term();
        cout << '+';
        Rest();
    }else if(LookAhead == '-'){
        Match('-');
        Term();
        cout << '-';
        Rest();
    }else{

    }
}

void Rest_(){
    if(LookAhead == '*'){
        Match('*');
        Factor();
        cout << '*';
        Rest_();
    }else if(LookAhead == '/'){
        Match('/');
        Factor();
        cout << '/';
        Rest_();
    }else{

    }
}

void Factor(){
    if(isdigit(LookAhead)){
        cout << LookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
    }
}
```

So now is there any experts who can help me to understand with the infix to prefix conversion translation scheme, it will be appreciated.

We can test through parse tree. If we can generate something like **-9+52** prefix string from example string **9-5+2** .

*Tell me if i need to explain more about my infix to postfix conversion translation scheme and code to get better understanding.*

Thanks in Advance !

**Edited :**
simply I am having a problem finding out the infix to prefix expression conversion translation scheme. As an example,
My input :

```
9-5+2
```

Expected Output :

```
-9+52
```

And I want to achieve this with the same structure I have shown above with infix to postfix conversion.
That is all !

Comment: Do your code work as it should, and you only want a code-review? Then post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. If it *doesn't* work, then you need to elaborate on your problem (like showing us some specific input, the expected and actual output, and what you have tried to debug the problem). And if you have done it yet, then please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Search reverse Polish notation

Comment: @EdHeal Can you please elaborate on that

Comment: @Ray Just google.

Comment: Just Google it. Converts infix to postfix. Can find algorithms to do that

Comment: @EdHeal: postfix != prefix

Comment: Guys I am trying to find infix to prefix translation scheme, not infix to postfix ... ?

Comment: You can just cconvert it by reading backwards

Comment: Please read my whole problem before commenting, I can read it backwards but that is not programming, I have asked, is there any translation scheme as I have mentioned above to convert infix to prefix expression, not by converting infix to postfix and just reverse it.

Comment: Do a search for polish notation. Wikipedia has lots of details

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to construct an [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) while you are parsing, and then recursively walk the tree using a [preorder traverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

You could also construct the string as you go (as suggested [here by @ChrisDodd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045060/1566221), for example), but:

- that's not a recursive solution :), and
- it involves a lot of string copying, so it will probably have quadratic running time.

It may also seem tempting to do the postfix conversion into some kind of temporary data structure (a stack, for example), and then recursively walk the postfix representation "evaluating" by printing the prefix expression. This will certainly work, but you will run into the problem that traversing the postfix representation in the natural way will first visit the *right-hand* argument of each expression, whereas what you want first is the *left-hand* argument. That means that you need to construct the string backwards, which involves another temporary datastructure (another stack, for example).

On the whole, the AST solution is cleaner, and provides a good basis for adding more functionality in the future.

Comment: I have followed the recursive way and just used a temporal storing concept and became success on what I wanted to do, please review my answer here, thanks for the help !

Comment: @Ray: I suppose you've tested it with expressions more complicated than `9-5+2`, right? I have a hard time believing thatva single temporary is sufficient to store the entire stack of unprinted values. Does `1*2+3*4` correctly output `+*12*34`? I suppose that the fact that you don't seem to parse parentheses limits the complexity of the expression but unless that is clearly in the requirements, it seems like a massive omission. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I have used a temporal variable to store my digits and checked and printed recursively the operators with maintaining the precedence of orders.

My Solution :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const char input[] = "9-5+2";
int index = 0;
char LookAhead = input[index];
char TempLookAhead = 'x';

void Match(char newChar);
void Factor();
void Rest_();
void Rest();
void Term();
void Expression();


int main(){
    Expression();
    return 0;
}

void Match(char newChar){
    if(newChar == LookAhead){
        index++;
        LookAhead = input[index];
    }
}

void Expression(){
    Term();
    Rest();
    cout << TempLookAhead;
}

void Term(){
    Factor();
    Rest_();
}

void Rest(){
    if(LookAhead == '+'){
        cout << '+';
        cout << TempLookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
        Term();
        Rest();
    }else if(LookAhead == '-'){
        cout << '-';
        cout << TempLookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
        Term();
        Rest();
    }else{

    }
}

void Rest_(){
    if(LookAhead == '*'){
        cout << '*';
        cout << TempLookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
        Factor();
        Rest_();
    }else if(LookAhead == '/'){
        cout << '/';
        cout << TempLookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
        Factor();
        Rest_();
    }else{

    }
}

void Factor(){
    if(isdigit(LookAhead)){
        TempLookAhead = LookAhead;
        Match(LookAhead);
    }
}
```