# strcat for unlimited string in c

Tags: c, string, concatenation, strcat

---

I want to implement strcat in c but for unlimited string, the function will allocate the necessary memory required for the final string, I came up with this :

```
char* strcat_ex(const char* str, ...) {
    if(!str)return 0;

    const char* current = str;
    char* res = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);

    // calculate the length of the final string
    size_t len = 0;
    for(; current; current = va_arg(args, char *))
        len += strlen(current);

    // allocate the string
    res = malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
    if(!res)return 0;

    // copy the strings to the final destination
    size_t cur = 0;
    for(; current; current = va_arg(args, char *)) {
        size_t cur_len = strlen(current);
        memcpy_s(res + cur, cur_len, current, cur_len);
    }

    va_end(args);
    return res;
}
```

- Is there any standard function already implemented.
- If not how can I improve this code, for example :

  1-I am calculating the length of the strings twice, how can I calculate them only once.

  2-Is there any security issues.

  3-Other suggestion to improve the code.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for that question.

Comment: `va_arg(current,int)` ? Not `char *`?

Comment: @dxramax  Why is there used the type int in current = va_arg(args, int)?

Comment: `strcat_ex` is a [bad name choice](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.13). Better `dxramax_strcat`.

Comment: Have you looked at `asprintf`? It's not the same, obviously, since it needs an explicit format, but it is often even more useful as a result.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be assuming that `va_arg` will automatically restart the argument scan (it won't), or you didn't paste the code where you make a copy of the `va_list`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to include the first string (`str`) in your length computation and your concatenated output.

Comment: @rici, do not overlook that `asprintf()` is a GNU-specific extension, so not necessarily a viable approach.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: It's an extension, to be sure, and it was first included in the Gnu libc, but it is also available on *BSD for quite some time, so I don't think "Gnu-specific" is a bit of an overstatement (http://www.manpages.info/macosx/asprintf.3.html#sect9). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685109/does-c-have-any-tools-for-doing-string-addition/30687023) for a shim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some general commentary.

```
if(!str)return 0;
```

While the constant `0` is guaranteed to be equivalent to the null pointer, I don't believe checking a pointer if it's false is. This probably isn't a problem for the common environments, but it's a bad habit to poke the C compatibility dragons *especially* if you're coming from a Windows background where it will be very tempting to get addicted to Microsoft extensions, and *especially* if you don't have an encyclopedic knowledge of the C standard. Don't poke the edge cases. If you mean null, use `NULL`.

Speaking of Microsoft extensions, [`memcpy_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wes2t00f.aspx) is a non-standard Microsoft extension. Either use `memcpy` or provide a compatibility wrapper.

`va_arg` has to be reinitialized on each use, it will not restart on its own. Think of `va_start` and `va_end` like braces around the use of `va_args`. The basic pattern is this:

```
va_start(args, first);
for(
    current = first;
    current != NULL;
    current = va_arg(args, char *)
) {
    ...
}
va_end(args);
```

You can't tell how many variable arguments there are, `va_arg` will keep reading whatever garbage is on the stack. You either have to pass in the number of arguments, which is error prone, or use a sentinel value like making the last argument NULL.

I would consider calling it something other than `strcat*` because it has a different interface. Using it like `strcat` invites a hard to debug error. `strcat` has the form `strcat( dest, src )` whereas your function is `dest = strcat_ex( src, src, ... )`. It will be very tempting for someone to write `strcat_ex( dest, src, src, ... )`.

The name which comes to mind is `strjoin`. `join` functions in other languages include the ability to supply a delimiter. This suggests a useful feature you could add to the function, you'll often want to join strings with a delimiter like `", "` or `" "`, that would be the first argument.

---

To avoid having to read all the strings twice, you can take advantage that the number of arguments will be quite small. The number of arguments are constrained by the size of the stack and the sanity of the programmer. So it's cheaper to go through the small number of arguments multiple times than it is to call `strlen` on the strings multiple times.

You need three loops through the arguments.

1. Figure out how many arguments there are.

   - Allocate an array to hold their lengths.
2. Store the string lengths and their total length.

   - Allocate the destination.
3. Copy the strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* strjoin(const char* first, ...) {
    if( first == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    va_list args;
    int i;
    const char *current;

    // 1. Figure out how many arguments there are.
    va_start(args, first);
    size_t num_args = 0;
    for(
        current = first;
        current != NULL;
        current = va_arg(args, char *)
    ) {
        num_args++;
    }
    va_end(args);

    //   * Allocate an array to hold their lengths.
    size_t str_sizes[num_args];

    // 2. Store the string lengths and their total length.
    size_t dest_size = 0;
    va_start(args, first);
    for(
        i = 0, current = first;
        current != NULL;
        i++, current = va_arg(args, char *)
    ) {
        str_sizes[i] = strlen(current);
        dest_size += str_sizes[i];
    }
    va_end(args);

    //     * Allocate the destination.
    char *dest = malloc(dest_size + 1);
    if( dest == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // 3. Copy the strings.
    char *dest_pos = dest;
    va_start(args, first);
    for(
        i = 0, current = first;
        current != NULL;
        i++, current = va_arg(args, char *)
    ) {
        memcpy( dest_pos, current, str_sizes[i] );
        dest_pos += str_sizes[i];
    }
    va_end(args);

    // Add the final null byte
    dest_pos[0] = '\0';

    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char *all = strjoin( "foo", "bar", "baz", "biff", "wibble", NULL );
    puts(all);
}
```

Comment: ` size_t str_sizes[num_args]; ` => expression must have a constant value, I think only a dynamic allocation is feasible here.

Answer (score 1):

Before this loop

```
size_t cur = 0;
for(; current; current = va_arg(args, char *)) {
    size_t cur_len = strlen(current);
    memcpy_s(res + cur, cur_len, current, cur_len);
}
```

you have to reinitialize `args` using the macro `va_start`.

The variable `cur` is not being changed in the loop and always equal to 0.  So all strings are copied at the same address `res + 0`.

Before each exit from the program you have to invoke the macro `va_end`.

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

char * strcat_ex( const char *s, ... )
{
    char *result = NULL;

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        va_list ap;

        size_t n = 0;

        va_start( ap, s );

        for ( const char *p = s; p != NULL; p = va_arg( ap, const char * ) )
        {
            n += strlen( p );
        }

        va_end( ap );

        ++n;

        result = ( char * )malloc( n );

        if ( result != NULL )
        {
            n = 0;

            va_start( ap, s );

            for ( const char *p = s; p != NULL; p = va_arg( ap, const char * ) )
            {
                strcpy( result + n, p );
                n += strlen( p );
            }

            va_end( ap );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s;

    s = strcat_ex( "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", NULL );

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    s = strcat_ex( "Hello", " ", "World!", NULL );

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
12345
Hello World!
```

You can add a check that the total length of all the strings is not greater than the maximum value that can be stored in an object of the type `size_t`. That is that there is np overflow.

Comment: NULL  is required to be the last parameter, clever way to know the last argument without providing the number of arguments, thanks.

Comment: Code is much, much simpler to read if you check for an error and deal with it immediately (ie. [early exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit)) rather than checking for no error and nesting ever deeper.

Comment: @Schwern I can not agree with you relative to this function implementation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Any particular reason? [I rewrote it to demonstrate how much simpler it is](https://gist.github.com/schwern/ccaa8d4d2868a520592e49dabc5d310d). The code reads linearly, it has no branches of consequence. With the error check and handling together, its very easy to tell what happens on error and what gets returned.

Comment: @Schwern The more exits the more you have to check that all clean up  operations are made before each exit. It is like using goto statements. Such a code is difficult to modify because you need to be sure that the modifications do not break the clean up operations.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah, that's [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) talking. Having too many returns is a problem, but blindly adhering to a single return can also complicate the rest of the code. "Early exit" for errors and argument checks is a common exception to "single return". In this case there's no cleanup, so there's no point in adhering to a single return. As for maintenance, understanding nested, single return code is more difficult, its hard to tell nesting resulting from the single return policy from nesting due to code logic.

Comment: @Schwern I could agree with you when there were many multiline checks at the beginning of the program. But it is not the case. The function does something if the parameter is not equal to NULL and this approach if ( s != NULL ) do the job; is clear enough.