# My parser doesn't realize that it should have taken the second branch of a rule

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am creating a parser for files that contain data about airport runways.

You have probably seen numbers at the end of runways, such as:

```
24L

24L-36R
```

Read as: `24 Left`, `24 Left/36 Right`

The numbers are called "runway designators".

A runway may be labeled with either a `designator` or `designator hyphen designator`.

Correspondingly, I have this rule (a choice with two branches) in my `.y` file:

```
rwydsg: RUNWAY  { $$ = concat(3, "<RunwayDesignator>", $1, "</RunwayDesignator>"); }
 | RUNWAY '-' RUNWAY { $$ = concat(7, "<RunwayDesignator_1>", $1, "</RunwayDesignator_1>", "<Hyphen>-</Hyphen>", "<RunwayDesignator_2>", $3, "</RunwayDesignator_2>"); }
;
```

The concat() function is a little function that I created. It works fine.

With this input:

```
24L
```

I get this output:

```
<RunwayDesignator>24L</RunwayDesignator>
```

Perfect!

With this input:

```
24L-36R
```

I get no output. Why is that?

Here is my input file:

```
24R-36L
```

Here is my ".l" file:

```
%{
#include "helloworld.tab.h"
%}

RWY [0-9]{2,2}(C|L|R)

%%
"-"             { return yytext[0]; }
{RWY}           { yylval.sval = malloc(yyleng + 1); strcpy(yylval.sval, yytext); return(RUNWAY); }
\n              { return(EOL); }
%%
int yywrap(){ return 1;}
```

Here is my ".y" file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utilities.h"
int yylex(void);
extern FILE *yyin;
void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

%union
{
  char *sval;
}
%token <sval> RUNWAY
%token EOL

%type <sval> rwydsg

%%

start: rwydsg               { printf("%s", $1); }

rwydsg: RUNWAY              { $$ = concat(3, "<RunwayDesignator>", $1, "</RunwayDesignator>"); }
 | RUNWAY '-' RUNWAY        { $$ = concat(7, "<RunwayDesignator><RunwayDesignator_1>", $1, "</RunwayDesignator_1>", "<Hyphen>-</Hyphen>", "<RunwayDesignator_2>", $3, "</RunwayDesignator_2></RunwayDesignator>"); }
;

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *msg)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", msg);
}
```

Here is my concat() function:

```
char *concat(int numargs, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    // The va_start macro enables access to the variable arguments following the 
    // last fixed argument (in this case, the last fixed argument is named numargs).
    va_start(ap, numargs);
    // T va_arg(va_list ap, T)
    // The va_arg macro expands to an expression of type T that corresponds to the 
    // next value in ap 
    size_t size = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numargs; i++) {
      size += sizeof va_arg(ap, T);
    }
    size++;
    char *buffer = calloc(1, size);
    for (int i=0; i<numargs; i++) {
      strcat(buffer, va_arg(ap, T));
    }
    // End traversal of the variable arguments
    va_end(ap);
    return (char *)buffer;
}
```

Comment: Bison parsers don't quietly give up when they can't parse the input - they produce a syntax error message (unless your `yyerror` function is empty). Either way, Bison won't just pick one alternative arbitrarily and then error out when things don't work out afterwards. First of all, Bison parsers don't work top-down like that. And more importantly, if Bison can't figure out which action to pick in some situation, it will warn you about a conflict. Since you didn't mention any conflicts, I'm assuming that wasn't the case here.

Comment: Anyway, you should post a [MCVE] that can be used to reproduce your problem. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the part of the grammar you posted and without further information, I could only guess randomly (like maybe your `concat` function produces an empty string when given too many arguments; or it overflows some buffer somewhere, which through the power of UB prevents any output; or your lexer produces a different token for `24L36R` and that particular token is quietly accepted without any output; or ...).

Comment: Thanks for the comments @sepp2k  Per your recommendation, I provided a minimum reproducible example, including the code for my concat() function.

Comment: How does this compile: `va_arg(ap, T)`.  `T` is not declared anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `concat` function is broken.

First of all, it does not initialize `size`, leading to undefined behavior. You'll need to initialize it to 0.

Second of all, it uses `sizeof va_arg(ap, T)` (which is the same as just `sizeof(T)`) to calculate the size of `buffer`. You didn't include the definition of `T`, but assuming it's a typedef for `char*` (which is the only way the code makes any sense), that will end up just adding 8 to `size` each time (or whatever the size of a pointer is on your platform). Since that's often less than the actual size of the strings (which you'd need `strlen` to find), you'll end up with a buffer that's too small to hold all the characters you're trying to write into it.

Also you never do anything with the string produced by `rwydsg`, so it really shouldn't produce any output on either input. But I imagine you just left that part out of the code you posted here.

Comment: Hello @sepp2k Thank you again for your excellent comments. Yes, I see that in the concat() function I forgot to initialize size. I made the change. However, even before making that change, it worked fine, e.g, printf("concat = %s\n", concat(7, "<RunwayDesignator_1>", "24L", "</RunwayDesignator_1>", "<Hyphen>-</Hyphen>", "<RunwayDesignator_2>", "36R", "</RunwayDesignator_2>")); produces the desired result. In the .y file I did indeed forget to show the start rule, which I now show. Unfortunately, the behavior is the same - no output.

Comment: @RogerCostello It may have worked fine for you, but I got a segmentation fault when I ran it. That's the trouble with undefined behavior: it's unpredictable.

Comment: Hello @sepp2k Yep, you are right, my concat() function is busted and that's what is causing the parser to behave wacky. Thank you again!

Comment: @roger: you might find [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687023/1566221) useful. I find it more useful than just concat.